# C# Check if input is valid date

Tags: c#, date, time

I am working on a calendar. And here I want to check if the users input is a date and if it's not showing an error. I heard about `DateTime.TryParse`. How can I use this here properly? Can maybe anyone explain it in simple words?

```
    public void addMeeting()
    {
      string readAddMeeting;
      var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}; // I copied this

      Console.WriteLine("Add a schedule for specific dates: ");

      readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: loop over your array of formats until you successfully parse the input, if no success till the end handle that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx has a nice example on how ot use tryparse itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) in this way:

```
public void addMeeting()
{
    var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}; 
    Console.WriteLine("Add a schedule for specific dates: ");
    string readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine();
    DateTime scheduleDate;
    bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        readAddMeeting,
        dateFormats,
        DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out scheduleDate);
    if(validDate)
        Console.WriteLine("That's a valid schedule-date: {0}", scheduleDate.ToShortDateString());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid date: {0}", readAddMeeting);
}
```

The method returns a `bool` indicating whether it could be parsed or not and you pass a `DateTime` variable as `out` parameter which will be initialized if the date was valid.

Note that i'm using `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` because you don't want to use the local `DateTime` format but one that works in any culture. Otherwise the `/` in `dd/MM/yyyy` would be replaced with your current culture's date separators. [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: Nice find with TryParseExact! Didn't think that it would be different in terms of taking only strings as possible DateTimeFormats (I don't get why TryParse only takes strings while TryParseExact also takes a whole string array). Nice find!

Comment: Okay, I just copied your code to see what happens. But it shows me "The Name DateTimeFormatInfo  AND DateTimeStyles does not exist in the current context". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user5462581: you have to add `using System.Globalization` or write it out: `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`. I prefer the former.

Comment: The former is the 2nd one ?

Comment: @user5462581: no, the first with the `using` directive. You know what it is? You have to put it on top of your class.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx But if you only need it in a small portion of your class it is acceptable to write the fully qualified name like in `System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None`. It's just a matter of readability. Once you're familiar with those  namespaces, classes and enums you don't want to repeat the fully qualified name everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I am known with the namespaces and the using directive but kind of new to C# and programing in general. Thanks for your example and your explanation.

Comment: @Thomas: `TryParse` only takes the input string because it's using the format of the current or specified culture. If you want to use a specific format you have to use `TryParseExact`. There you have the option to use the overload that takes a single `string` as format or the other overload that takes a `string[]` of allowed formats.

Comment: ah that explains it tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Even if it sounds a bit brutal, but it seems ike you should do some readup on arrays/lists, foreach loops and DateTime.TryParse.

That aside you have different possible date formats and want to see if one of them is valid. If we take the  example from the msdn homepage for tryparse https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx  and use foreach it becomes quite easy:

```
public void addMeeting()
{
    string readAddMeeting;
    var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}; // I copied this
    bool isDateOk = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Add a schedule for specific dates: ");

    readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine();

    foreach (string myDateFormat in dateFormats)
    {
        DateTime dateValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(readAddMeeting, dateValue)) 
        {
            isDateOk = true;
        }
    }

    if (isDateOk == false)
    {
        Console.Writeline("Sorry this is not a valid date");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I should do some readup with this stuff. I'm pretty new to programing.